# Probability problem involving selection of balls from a box

Tags: probability

I came across this problem when dosing my cat with 1/2 tablets. Transferring the problem to a balls in a box problem,

I have a box containing N balls, all black. I select balls from the box as follows:
I randomly draw a ball from the box.  If it is black, I replace it in the box with a red ball. If it is red, no replacement is made. As I repeatedly draw balls from the box, I would like to know:

- for each draw, what is the probability that the ball drawn is black?
- what is the expected number of black balls in the box?
- what is the expected number of total balls in the box?

I observe that

- there will be 2*N draws
- the total number of balls in the box monotonically decreases

For small numbers of N, I can enumerate all the possible combinations, but for large N?

-- Greg

Comment: "If it is red, no replacement is made" do you mean you don't add it back ?

Comment: "If it is black, I replace it in the box with a red ball" do you put this ball back with a red ball (adding two balls) ?

Comment: Since it is written "the total number of balls in the box monotonically decreases", black balls drawn wouldn't be replaced

Comment: @Quarantiner As I interpret the problem, if the ball drawn is black, it is discarded, and a red ball is put into the box in its place.  This causes no change to the number of balls.  Further, the number of balls in the box forms a non-increasing sequence (meaning the sequence will sometimes decrease from one element to the next).  Therefore, I infer that if the ball drawn is red, it is not replaced, and the total number of balls in the box decreases by 1.  This is the only inference that I can imagine that would allow the number of balls in the box to ever decrease.

Comment: For what it's worth, in my opinion, this query is no walk in the park.

Comment: user2661923 is correct, but I see that I need to improve my description:
If a black ball is drawn, the black ball is discarded (not put in the box) and a  red ball placed  in the box. If a red ball is drawn, it is simply removed and no addition to the box is made.